# Python - having trouble with for loop, and getting columns as lists

Tags: python, excel, list, for-loop

I've just started learning python recently because of work, and I'm struggling with a for loop in my code. I want my program to output values for amount of ammonia produced hourly, which is dependent on the cells in Excel (attached below), and I need the columns for 'H2 consumed by NH3' and 'Actual Stored' as lists in Python in order to move forward. However, when I run this code, the process is constantly running and doesn't stop, which made me realize I've messed up somewhere but I can't tell where.

```
hourly_H2_prod = [hourly_elec*1000/avg_pwr_use for hourly_elec in elec_list]
H2_sum = sum(hourly_H2_prod)
avg_hourly_H2_consumed = avg_hourly_NH3_prod*3/17.31

init_H2_stored = H2_sum/365*Storage_days        #highlighted cell in Excel screenshot

actual_H2_stored = [init_H2_stored]
hourly_H2_consumed = []
for i in range(1,len(hourly_H2_prod)):
    for j in range(len(actual_H2_stored)):
        hourly_H2_consumed.append(max(min(avg_hourly_H2_consumed,actual_H2_stored[j]),0))
        actual_H2_stored.append(max(min(init_H2_stored,actual_H2_stored[j]+hourly_H2_prod[i]-hourly_H2_consumed[j]),0))
```

I have already managed to get the list format for the 'hourly H2 production' column

[(this is to show how the values are dependent on each other, for actual-H2-stored)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SM7yz.png)

[(how values depend for hourly-H2-consumed)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHbbq.png)

I think I'm messing up when I need to iterate using the previous variable as shown in the excel formula. I also hope I've explained everything fully, I appreciate any help!

Comment: Please use copy&paste instead of images - see [ask] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: It would not let me do that since I am a new user and need to have 10 reputation points or something

Comment: rather than `for i in range(1,len(X))` do `for ii,value in enumerate(X)` it's more pythonic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, @VonWooDSoN you were right the nested loop did mess everything up. I removed the line altogether and instead just put in this, and it worked perfectly and now I'm getting the values in the list form I need, so thank you for the tip!

```
for i in range(1,len(hourly_H2_prod)):
    hourly_H2_consumed.append(max(min(avg_hourly_H2_consumed,actual_H2_stored[i-1]),0))
    actual_H2_stored.append(max(min(init_H2_stored,actual_H2_stored[i-1]+hourly_H2_prod[i]-hourly_H2_consumed[i-1]),0))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to see where your error is, but I cannot run your code.
I think that the issue is *truly* in that nested "j" for loop.  As of python 3 a `range` is a generator, so it's possible that adding to that list in the nested loop is going to create an endless loop because the `len` function *may* be called each iteration.  Try replacing it with this :`for j in list(range(len(actual_H2_stored))):`

I added the `list` to the `range` so that it'll fully preprocess your list's length before you start iteration.

Comment: Tried replacing that line as you mentioned and the code still doesn't run. I also tried removing that line altogether, replaced the ```j``` in front of actual_H2_stored with ```[i-1]``` and the ```j``` in front of hourly_H2_consumed with ```[i]```, and I got an IndexError: list index out of range.

Comment: I figured it out, posted it as an answer so that others can see, thank you for the tip!

Comment: I’m sorry that I could not provide a concrete answer. Modifying a data structure while it’s being iterated over (a for-loop) is a general “code smell” (thing to be avoided, and a place to look for bugs). I’m glad that you found your answer. Happy hacking.